# ruby on rails - presenting many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have recipe and ingredient in a many to many relation.

I have defined the following commands in my presentation.

```
<div>
  <%= render :partial => 'ingredients/form',
             :locals => {:form => recipe_form} %>
</div>
```

the partial begins with

```
<%= form_for(@ingredient) do |ingredient_form| %>
```

but received @ingredient nill.
Then I tried

```
<%= recipe_form.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'ingredient_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

where my render was

```
<p class="fields">
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
</p>
```

but nothing was printed.
then I tried

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <%= ingredient.name %>
<% end %>
```

and only then all of the ingredients were printed. 
What was I doing wrong in the previous tries ? 
Thank you.

my ingredient recipe relation defined as follows

```
 class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredient_recipes
   has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredient_recipes
   ...

 class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredient_recipes
   has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes
   ...

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_recipes  ,:reject_if  => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank?}


 class IngredientRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at, :ingredient_id, :order, :recipe_id
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
 end
```

Comment: I believe @ingredient is nil because of whatever is going on in your controller's action. Do you mind editing your post with that?

Comment: thanks. But it does show the ingredients in my last try - @recipe.ingredients.each . doesnt that mean that my ingredients are there? I have controllers for recipe and ingredienet and model for them and IngredientRecipe too. what method should I add in the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't exactly specify what you are trying to do, so I am presuming you have a page that shows a recipe, with many ingredients that can be edited and added to. In your controller you have something like:

```
class RecipeController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]
  end
end
```

I am also presuming that you are looking to have a form that post backs to the create action. I therefore think you want a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |form| %>

  <%= label_for :name %>
  <%= text_field :name %>

  <%= form.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredients_fields| %>
    <div class="ingredient">
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Also, change your recipe to accept nested attributes for `ingredients`, not `ingredient_recipes`:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredient_recipes
   has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes
   ...

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if  => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank?}
```

And finally, add attr_accessible for your content:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  ...
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your preassumptions were accurate. I had already written all your suggestions but the last one. Changing  has_many :ingredient_recipes to :ingredients did it all. BTW should I leave both lines has_many :ingredient_recipes &&
   has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes. as in my original question?

Comment: Glad that worked. Yes, you need both of those lines in recipe.